# Javascript add count to a number with comma

Tags: javascript, parseint

So I have this

```
var str=document.getElementById('elem').innerHTML;
str=parseInt(str)+1;

<span id="elem">1,500</span>
```

and I can't get it to take the entire number and add one (+1) to the number without taking comma off. Can you suggest something?

Comment: try `str=parseInt(str.replace(',','')) + 1`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277948/commas-messing-with-number-input-in-javascript

Comment: `+'1,500'.replace(',', '') + 1`

Comment: I can understand that I need to replace a comma. I was asking how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the commas by replacing them with an empty string, then you can parse the string.

Remember the second parameter in the `parseInt` method that specifies the base, so that it doesn't use base 8 for zero padded values.

```
var num = parseInt(str.replace(/,/g, ''), 10) + 1;
```

If you want to put the changed number back formatted with commas, you can use:

```
var s = num.toString();
for (var i = s.length - 3; i > 0; i -= 3) {
  s = s.substr(0, i) + ',' + s.substr(i);
}
document.getElementById('elem').innerHTML = s;
```