# How would I convert the text inside this class to just an int?

Tags: javascript

I'm making some code that scans an item for its price, and the price is located inside a class "cash". The text inside the cash class looks like this

```
                                        1,000
```

I need to find a way to convert it to just an integer, rather than a string with lots of empty white space
I tried doing this

```
var cash = document.getElementsByClassName('cash')[0].innerHTML
var parser = parseInt(cash)
console.log(parser)
```

It just returns "1"

I need to also make it so that it gets rid of the comma, so if the price is 1,000, it will return 1000, and I need to be able to use it as an integer.

Comment: Why not use a regular expression to remove all the punctuation and whitespace?

Comment: [Commas messing with number input in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277948/commas-messing-with-number-input-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
var cash = "1,000";
var parser = parseInt(cash.replace(/,/g, ""));
document.write(parser);
```

*(Note the added semicolons to the end of each line)*

This uses `cash.replace(/,/g, "")` to replace any occurance of a comma in *cash*, with 'nothing'; i.e. removes any commas

Comment: Note: This won't behave as expected for millions, etc. – `"1,000,000".replace(",", "") === "1000,000"`. Given a string, `.replace()` will only replace the first occurrence. [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Great! You can mark it as the correct answer by clicking the green tick to the left of the answer @JDoe

Answer (score 0):

Just remove everything, that doesn't match numbers wuth regex: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NeoSelcev/uh8hpgt6/1/)

```js
var cash = document.getElementsByClassName('cash')[0].innerHTML
var parser = parseFloat(cash.replace(/[^0-9|^.]/g, ''))
alert(parser)
```

```html
<div class="cash">1,000.23</div>
```